# Debugging in Jison

Tags: javascript, parsing, bison, parser-generator, jison

I'm using Jison to write a parser. This is my grammar:

```
{
    "program": [
        ["statements EOF", "return $1;"]
    ],
    "statements": [
        ["statement",            "$$ = $1;"],
        ["statements statement", "$$ = $1 + '\\n' + $2;"]
    ],
    "statement": [
        ["expression NEWLINE", "$$ = $1 + ';';"]
    ],
    "expression": [
        ["NUMBER",                "$$ = yytext;"],
        ["expression expression", "$$ = $1 + ', ' + $2;"]
    ]
}
```

When I run it however I get the following error message:

```
Conflict in grammar: multiple actions possible when lookahead token is NUMBER in
state 9
- reduce by rule: expression -> expression expression
- shift token (then go to state 5)

States with conflicts:
State 9
  expression -> expression expression . #lookaheads= NEWLINE NUMBER
  expression -> expression .expression
  expression -> .NUMBER
  expression -> .expression expression
```

What am I supposed to make of this debug message? How would you explain this message in simple English? What does the period in `expression -> expression expression .` mean? What are `.expression` and `.NUMBER`? How are they different from `expression` and `NUMBER` respectively?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What am I supposed to make of this debug message?

A grammar conflict means the parser can reach a state where it could follow multiple rules, but it doesn't have enough information to determine which one to follow (or worse, the grammar is ambiguous). You'll have to tweak the grammar to eliminate the conflicts. Often, this just takes practice to get right.

> What does the period in expression -> expression expression . mean?

The period represents the position of the parser. So, in that rule, the parser would have just parsed two expressions, and is now in state 9. When the period is at the end of the rule, that means the rule can be "reduced", and grouped into a single `expression` non-terminal in this case. However, it can only reduce if the next token (the lookahead) is a `NEWLINE` or a `NUMBER`.

In `expression -> .NUMBER`, the parser has just encountered a NUMBER token, which it can "shift", then move to a new state.

The conflict occurs because the parser can reduce or shift when it encounters a `NUMBER` token.

Edit: To resolve your conflict, we need to split that expression rule into distinct non-terminals. Having the same non-terminal in sequence is bound to produce conflicts.

e.g.

```
{
    "program": [
        ["statements EOF", "return $1;"]
    ],
    "statements": [
        ["statement",            "$$ = $1;"],
        ["statements statement", "$$ = $1 + '\\n' + $2;"]
    ],
    "statement": [
        ["expression NEWLINE", "$$ = $1 + ';';"]
    ],
    "expression": [
        ["expression expression_base", "$$ = $1 + ', ' + $2;"],
        ["expression_base", "$$ = $1;"]
    ],
    "expression_base": [
        ["NUMBER",                "$$ = yytext;"]
    ]
}
```

Here's a [nice resource](http://lambda.uta.edu/cse5317/notes/node12.html) for more background on these types of grammars.

Comment: Thank you Zach. Is there any way to explicitly specify the associativity of a production? I created a precedence level `["left", "COMMA"]` and then tried to set it for the production `expression expression` as `{ "prec": "COMMA" }`. That however didn't work. How would you propose I rewrite this production. I want to be able to type a string such as `2 3 5 7` and parse it as an expression `(((2 3) 5) 7)`. I've been stuck here for a frustrating bit of time and I can't seem to wrap my head around the problem.